# Filtering DataTable that contains objects

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Before I had a `DataTable` filled with `string` values.
I used the `Select` method to filter data and it worked very well.

```
DataRow[] drs = dataTable.Select("[" + dataTable.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName + "] LIKE '%" + filter + "%'");
```

After some time the `string` values in the `DataTable` had to be changed to `Cell` objects which is an home made class containing the old value plus some other properties.

```
public class Cell
{
    public object Value { get; set; } /*This is the old string value*/
    public bool Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

I realized that my filter function won't work anymore.

Anyone have an idea how I should deal with the filtering of my `DataTable` which is now containing `Cell` objects instead of `strings`?

Comment: If I have understood it correctly you can use datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(x=>x.Value == "abc" && x.Property1 == "abcd");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kanchirks comment I came up with this solution.

```
EnumerableRowCollection erc = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => ((Cell)dr[columnIndex]).Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()));
```